# How to enable/disable a button dynamically with JavaScript, based on conditions with textfields

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following jsp page, consisting of 2 text fields, 2 password fields, 1 email field and 1 file-uploader, followed by a disabled button:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration Page</title> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <h3>Registration</h3>
        <form action="Myservlet" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <p>Name <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></p>
            <p>Lastname <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"></p>
            <p>Email <input type="email" name="email" id="email"></p>
            <p>Password <input type="password" name="password" id="password"></p>
            <p>Confirm password <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword"></p>
            <p>Photo <input type="file" name="photo"></p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="register" id="register" disabled></p>        
        </form>
        <script src="RegScript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My purpose is to enable and disable the button at run time using pure JavaScript, based on 2 conditions:

1. All the text fields, except the file-uploader, must all be filled in;
2. The password fields must match.

So I wrote the following JavaScript code:

RegScript.js

```
name = document.getElementById("name");
lastname = document.getElementById("lastname ");
email = document.getElementById("email");
password = document.getElementById("password");
confirmpassword = document.getElementById("confirmpassword");
register = document.getElementById("register");

//password matching & text fields checking


confirmpassword.addEventListener('input', () =>{
    if((name.value.length > 0)&&(lastname.value.length > 0)&&(email.value.length > 0)&&(confirmpassword.value === password.value)){
       register.disabled = false;
   }
   else{
       register.disabled = true;
   }
});

password.addEventListener('input', () =>{
    if((name.value.length > 0)&&(lastname.value.length > 0)&&(email.value.length > 0)&&(confirmpassword.value === password.value)){
       register.disabled = false;
   }
   else{
       register.disabled = true;
   }
});
```

The following script seems to work partially, but it has some errors: When I fill in all the text fields in order as they appear, in the moment that the passwords match the button is enabled, as well as if I delete the password it's disabled again, but if instead I delete one of the other three text fields (name, lastname or email) the button remains enabled, when it should not. What can I do to simplify the code (I'm not satisfied with the way I wrote my code, since it's redundant) and to solve to this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can DRY the validation logic in a `validate` function that runs whenever inputs change, which is set up using `addEventListener` on each of them.

This unifies the logic and makes it easy to extend later, for example you might check the emails `.validity.valid` property to see if it's an actual email.

This is a working snippet:

```js
let name = document.getElementById("name");
let lastname = document.getElementById("lastname");
let email = document.getElementById("email");
let password = document.getElementById("password");
let confirmpassword = document.getElementById("confirmpassword");
let register = document.getElementById("register");

[name, lastname, email, password, confirmpassword].forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener("input", validate)
})

const hasLength = input => input.value.trim().length > 0;

function validate() {
  let isValid =
    hasLength(name) &&
    hasLength(lastname) &&
    hasLength(email) &&
    hasLength(password) &&
    password.value == confirmpassword.value;
    
    console.log(isValid)
    register.disabled = !isValid;
    
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Registration Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Registration</h3>
  <form action="Myservlet" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p>Name <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></p>
    <p>Lastname <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"></p>
    <p>Email <input type="email" name="email" id="email"></p>
    <p>Password <input type="password" name="password" id="password"></p>
    <p>Confirm password <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword"></p>
    <p>Photo <input type="file" name="photo"></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="register" id="register" disabled></p>
  </form>
  <script src="RegScript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great solution, thank you! I didn't know you could add an EventListener so compactly to all the components. Now it works well and does its purpose.